# Bind Mocking Function inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, qunit

I am writing QUnit test case for my application . Basically I have three Files 
like below . DataServices.js has getObjectDetails  method which does ajax call
to get data and passes result in callback .

Resolver.js loads DataServices.js using require.

I am writing test case for Proxy.resolve  method , in which i want to avoid actual api call , to do this I created mock object of DataServices in Test.js and call Resolver proxy resolve method .

I tried using bind , But still points to actual method of DataServices.js not what I bind in Test.js

**DataServices.js**

```
define(["module"], function(module) {
"use strict";
 var Details = {
    getObjectDetails :function(param,callback){
       //API AJAX CALL
       // Callback once done
    }
 };
 return {Details : Details }
});
```

**Resolver.js**

```
define(["DataServices"],function(DataServices){
var Proxy= {
  resolve : function(){
  var Details = DataServices.Details ;
     Details.getObjectDetails("xyz", function(result){
         // Do Operation After Result
     });
  }

 };
 return {Proxy:Proxy}
});
```

**Test.js**

```
define(["Resolver.js" ],function(Resolver){

   var DataServices= {
    Details : {
        getObjectDetails : function(undefined,onSuccess, onError) {
            return onSuccess({"X":"Y"});
        }
      }
   };
  Resolver.Proxy.resolve.bind(DataServices);
  Resolver.Proxy.resolve(); // This is still calling DataServices.js Details 
                            // Not the above muck object

});
```

**In simple program , I want to call mock z function , not z which is inside x .
How to achieve this.**

```
var x = {
  z:function(b){
    console.log("Z Actual Function..."+b);
   },
  a : function(){
    this.z(3);
  }
};
var z = function(b){
  console.log("Mock ..."+b)
}

x.a.bind(z);
x.a();

//Z Actual Function...3
```

But I want Mock ...3 to print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First problem

Using `.bind` creates a [**new** function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), it doesn't change the value of `this` in the original function.

To use bind in your case you would do something like this instead:

```
var mockedA = x.a.bind(z);
mockedA();
```

If you want to call the function immediately without assigning it to a variable you can use [.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/call) or [.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/apply) instead.

eg:

```
x.a.call(z); // runs `a()` immediately with `this` set to `z`
```

### The second problem

By binding `x.a` to `z` you're changing the value of `this` to the value provided (the mock `z` function). So inside `x.a` when you call `this.z(3)` you're effectively trying to call `z.z(3)`, which is a non existent function and so will throw a `TypeError`.

There are probably better ways of doing it but this is a way that answers your question:

```js
var x = {
  z:function(b){
    console.log("Z Actual Function..."+b);
  },
  a : function(){
    this.z(3);
  }
};

var mock = {};
mock.z = function(b){
  console.log("Mock ..."+b)
}

// with bind
var mockXA = x.a.bind(mock);
mockXA();

// with call
//x.a.call(mock)
```

Comment: I tried Resolver.Proxy.resolve.bind(DataServices).call() it is still referring to DataServices.js getObjectDetails not mock one on test.js

Comment: I'm not very familiar with AMD style modules but the reason its not working probably is because Resolver.js is **not** using the `this` keyword like your reduced test case was. Bind only changes the value of the `this` keyword but `DataServices` is being supplied as an argument to the module constructor instead.

Comment: You got it correct , this keyword is not in DataServices , any way to hack the function without changing code . Because the system is in production and I don't have flexibility to change

Comment: You would probably have more luck mocking the DataServices.js module directly with something like https://github.com/ValeriiVasin/requirejs-mock.